# How to set textTransform to all components globally?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I want to capitalize all text in my muiv5 project. It should be default to capitalize unless stated in `sx` or styled on the component itself.

What I've tried is:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <IntlProvider
        locale="en"
        defaultLocale="en"
        messages={AppLocale.en.messages}
    >
        <CssBaseline />
        <GlobalStyles styles={{ root: { textTransform: "capitalize" } }} />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </IntlProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

But it doesn't work. Any best way to do this? Even `createTheme` is not working for me.

Note: I don't want to use `makeStyles`. Using Next.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow all the children of `body` to inherit the `textTransform` value.

```js
<GlobalStyles styles={{ body: { textTransform: "capitalize" } }} />
```